# Set author to the node automatically whenever the new user registered and also automatically authenticate the user

Tags: rules, emails

I have a Drupal site with content type `people`. In that content type I have a field that contains an email id.

What I want to do is, whenever the new user is registered, I want to compare the user's email with the email field of all the nodes with `people` as the content type. If these 2 fields match, then set the user as the author of that node.

I don't know how to execute this process.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: You requirement preety unique but using rules you can achieve this. Rules action when new user register compare in condition for both field. Event you need to set author. thats it.

Comment: I'm new to drupal. I know this can be execute using rules. I tried but it's not working because this people content type has more than 10k nodes I want to check user mail with all the nodes mail through loop. Can you explain me in steps.?

Comment: What do you mean with "automatically authenticate the user" (as in your title)? Your question details do not say anything about that part of the question title (I think) ...

Comment: I has configured some rules in my site. That is whenever the new user registered i'll get mail. After getting mail, manually i'll go and set the user role. Whenever the user role is set automatically the user 'll get password change mail. This user authentication flow only i mentioned in title.

Comment: OK, these flow details help a bit. But is your question also about how to simplify this part of your flow? If so can you provide some ore details about what part to simplify?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom module and  Use below logic hope it will work.

```
function hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $email = $account->email;
  $uid = $account->uid;

  $query = db_select('field_email', 'e');
  $query->addField('e', 'entity_id');
  $query->condition('e.field_email_data', $email, '=');
  $nids = $query->execute();

  foreach($nids as $nid){

    //Update node user
    $node = node_load($nid); // ...where $nid is the node id
    $node->uid    = $uid;
    node_save($node);

   //Add role to user 
   $role_name = 'member';
   if ($role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name)) {
     user_multiple_role_edit(array($uid), 'add_role', $role->rid);
   }

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm new to drupal. This ''ll be a big task.

Comment: anyother solution..?
Advance Thanks.

Comment: how to query and get all entity_ids from the field_email table

Comment: Hi @Bipin K, Can you tell me the query to get all entity_id's from the field_email table

Comment: This will help you to create custom module..http://webemania.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-module-in-drupal-in-three-easy-steps

Comment: what is your table name for email field ?

Comment: table name mean machine name.?

Comment: machine name is field_email

Comment: and one more thing i forget to mention. If user email presents in field_email table I have to set role to that user.

Comment: I added query to my answer..

Comment: Thanks. How to update node table user id by uid.?

Comment: I need answer for this comment
//Update node table user id by above $uid for all nids

Comment: Added in answer..

Comment: Hi Bipin, This will work in drupal 7.?

Comment: yes.. Of course..

Comment: Hi Bipin, That above code is not working. What to do now.?

Comment: Debug.. and find out the issue

Comment: I can debug it. First I want to know is, this module works are not..?

Comment: As per the code logic it should, I have not tried it personally as it is unique requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of what you'll need to get it to work using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module:

1. Create a rules component (= **Rule 1**, of type "component") with these parameters:

   - node id.
   - user id.
   - eMail id.

   Here is what the specs are for this Rules component:

   - **Condition**: If the eMail id of the user id (indicated in the parameter `userid id`) matches the eMail id indicated in the parameter `eMail id`.
   - **Action**: Update author id of the node (indicated in the parameter `node id`) to the user id indicated in the parameter `userid id`.
2. Create a rule (= **Rule 2**) containing a *Loop* that should be triggered (= **Event**) after a new user account is created. The goal of this rule is to loop over each of the nodes of content type "*People*". In each iteration of that loop you use an action which is to invoke the Rule Component as detailed in Step 1 (and which passes the required parameters for it). By using a Rules Component, you'll be able to add any "Conditions" you might need inside the "Loop" (in this case: check that the eMail Ids match).

## Bonus features

1. In the Rules component, if needed/appropriate, you might also do things like:

   - add additional conditions (e.g. because of changing requirements later on).
   - add additional actions (e.g. grant access to 1 or more roles for this user).
2. You only need site building skills to implement this solution (could be interesting for somebody new to Drupal).

## Video tutorials

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with using *Loops* in rules, then watch the video about [List and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops).

For a video that is fairly similar to what's needed in step 1 and step 2, refer to the 2nd video (= Solution video) about [Creating multiple back links](http://drupal.placeto.be/planning/creating-multiple-back-links). Some more details about how your scenario slightly differs from what is shown in that solution video:

- You are creating an entity reference **to** nodes also, but **from** a user (not a node).
- You need 3 parameters in your Rules component (instead of 2).

Comment: Can you explain about to crate rules components that is first step in the above answer in more detail.